# eslint Warning Unexpected unnamed async function , anyway to get rid if it?

Tags: javascript, async-await, eslint

When I defined my async function as :

```
module.exports.sendSmtpMessage = async function(keys, mailOptions) {  // <== warning
    await sendSmtpMessage(keys, mailOptions);
}

var sendSmtpMessage = async function(keys, mailOptions) {
...
}
```

update2

```
var sendMessage = async function sendMessage(keys, mailOptions) {
...
}

module.exports.sendSmtpMessage = async function sendSmtpMessage(keys, mailOptions) {
    await sendMessage(keys, mailOptions);
}
```

I get an eslint warning :

```
19:34  warning  Unexpected unnamed async function                          func-names
```

Is it a bad writing ?

thanks for feedback

****update 1**. as per Ankit's comment..**.

```
module.exports.sendSmtpMessage = async function sendSmtpMessage(keys, mailOptions) {  // <== warning
    await sendSmtpMessage(keys, mailOptions);
}

var sendSmtpMessage = async function(keys, mailOptions) { // <== warning and error !
...
}

23:7   error    'sendSmtpMessage' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
23:25  warning  Unexpected unnamed async function
```

solving one warning, now getting a warning + 1 error...

**update2**. need to change the order of definition and use ...  no more warnings or error ...

```
var sendMessage = async function sendMessage(keys, mailOptions) {
...
}

module.exports.sendSmtpMessage = async function sendSmtpMessage(keys, mailOptions) {
    await sendMessage(keys, mailOptions);
}
```

Comment: try `async function somename(keys .....`

Comment: Don't you want to `return await sendMessage(...);` to allow consuming code to await the result? Please revise your question and remove the answer/solution (there are now duplicated code blocks for the updates). Consider adding your own answer with the final solution or improve existing answers with more elaborate explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having named exports makes it easy organize your code.

```
const doSomething = async function(args) {
  // ...
}

const doSomethingElse = async function() {
    await doSomething(args);
}

module.exports = {
  doSomething: doSomething,
  doSomethingElse: doSomethingElse
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of that error, you can give a name to that `async` function like:

```
var sendSmtpMessage = async function sendSmtpMessage(keys, mailOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

linted correctly, with named functions :   defined then exported ...

```
const sendMessage = async function sendMessage(keys, mailOptions) {
    ....
};

module.exports.sendSmtpMessage = async function sendSmtpMessage(keys, mailOptions) {
  await sendMessage(keys, mailOptions);
};
```